# reassign value not work in operator = overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, new-operator

The MWE is

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class N {
public:
    float x;
    N() { x = 0.0; }
    N(float a) { x = a; }
    //N(N &n) { x = n.x; }
    N &operator=(float f) { cout << "########";return *new N(f); }
};



int main() {
    N a;
    a = 3.0;
    cout << a.x;
    return 0;
}
```

What I expect is: it prints 3, but it actually prints 0.  It seems the value didn't change.

Then I change it into

```
x = f; return *this;
```

It worked, why?

Comment: whereever you read that `operator=` should return the reference to a `new`ed object please read something else

Comment: The `*new N(f)` is returned as the evaluation of the assignment. `cout << (a = 0.3).x` returns 3.0 as it accesses the expression returned by the assignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it doesn't change.  You don't change it in your assignment operator.  Instead you return a pointer to a new value allocated on the heap...and ignore that result.

Comment: The memory leak is a bonus, I suppose.

Comment: Yes, I return a pointer to a new value allocated on the heap. But why the result was ignored? `a` get a new pointer. Of course, `a.x` will change, right?

Comment: No.  a does *not* get a new pointer.  a has not changed.  There is a brand new struct on the heap with the new value.  Hint:  C++ is not Java or C#

Comment: I don't think that either C++ nor Java would behave as the OP seems to expect.